# Will a U.S. citizen be able to open a bank account in Sweden?

Tags: immigration, banking, sweden

Years ago, my spouse and I moved to Switzerland. While living there, we found out that due to [FATCA laws](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/corporations/foreign-account-tax-compliance-act-fatca) and my spouse being a U.S. citizen, opening a bank account would be difficult. It was eventually resolved with the help of a bank that had a business relationship with my then employer.

I wanted to know whether or not similar factors could cause a problem when moving to Sweden, especially now that I am also a U.S. citizen.

Comment: Their is now a U.S. Tax treaty with Sweden. Some of those details may have made dealing with American expats much less onerous, but you will have to look up the details.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to know whether or not similar factors could cause a problem when moving to Sweden, especially now that I am also a U.S. citizen.

FATCA requirements haven't changed. A lot of European banks, when it was first adopted, decided to just avoid US customers in order to not deal with the onerous requirements the US imposes in FATCA.

Some banks has since adopted processes to facilitate that, others keep refusing to provide service to Americans. You'll have to shop around. It is likely that it would be much less of a problem now than it was 10 years ago, but you may still be refused by some banks.

Comment: The real world is not binary. Some banks will open (or maintain) accounts subject to FATCA, but charge the customer higher fees than the bank would charge a customer not subject to FATCA.